# JSCONSOLE does not work

Tags: javascript, debugging, mobile, browser

I followed the instructions:( point browser to http://jsconsole.com, type :listen, got the descriptor, and put that little script into my web page...) ,but I only got the following output:

```
Creating connection...
Connected to ...
sent remote command
```

Nothing from the console.log got displayed.

I tried both edge and google chrome on my windows 10.I also tried to install a local version under node.js, but still no luck.

Not sure what's wrong, can somebody help? Thanks

Comment: I do wonder if it even works any more :/ I'm trying to use it to debug a phone app, but it doesn't work. You should get an alert() come up when you first load the page. If not, check your Developer Tools in the browser to see if you get an error. I feel like its been abandoned, which is a real shame :(

Comment: Developer has disabled the remote feature: https://github.com/remy/jsconsole/issues/101